# Best Way to approach a 3D customisable Globe in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, 3d, flutter-layout, rendering, flutter-animation

following question:

I'm currently working on a **Travel App** and I thought of the idea of implementing an **3D Globe** that can be rotated by the user. I thought of the Globe as a basic White Sphere with the borders of the countries visible as a stroke. All countries that have been visited should be **filled with a color**.

I thought of implementing it with the *unity widget*, but I'd like to maintain a **lightweight feeling**.

Is there a way to **emulate** js or WebGL?

What do you think is the best way to approach this?

Thank you for your time

Linus

Comment: I did not try this, but I think this makes sense. https://github.com/zesage/flutter_earth

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview_flutter, I played with it a little bit to display planet models in javascript library three.js. Thanks to it you can use it like standard js instance of it with only one drawback that I didn't try to solve: I was unable to run it in browser mode as Flutter needs to emulate js itself  by platform speciffic way. There is option to load js/html code from local assets but then you will not be able to load models in js directly as you will face cors policy restrictions, then the only way is to pass models as json from flutter code. It works pretty well, supports two way communication between js and flutter so you can also add events to model etc.